Is it possible to recover messages with deleted user on Discord?
If someone has been messaging with a deleted user (banned) and since closed the DMs, is it possible to recover those DMs? Would requesting data from Discord of chat history include those DMs or are these erased entirely (versus simply anonymised)? Would it show up in an archive if the data was requested before that user was deleted?
